# If FragmentManager.beginTransaction() is not implemented, how can it return a FragmentTransaction object?

Tags: java, android, fragment

The following is some Android java code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = new ThisClassExtendsFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

I am confused by the call to beginTransaction(). It seems that this is an abstract method, and that it isn't implemented anywhere. How then can it return a FragmentTransaction object?

Comment: Interesting question. Both the docs and actually looking at the FragmentManager implementation say the same :D I'm baffled :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that this is an abstract method, and that it isn't implemented anywhere

The implementation is in an internal part of the Android SDK, that you will not be able to see from the JavaDocs.

In this case, it is implemented by `FragmentManagerImpl`, a nested class inside [the `FragmentManager` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-6.0.1_r63/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java).

Comment: You're always there to save the day. Love the book btw! Keep up the great work.